# How do I set shiny app size in RStudio windowed mode?

Tags: r, shiny

I was wondering, if there is a way to start a shinyapp in RStudio in window mode with prespecified window size. I found a workaround via creating a new file with following code:

```
{library(shiny)
vwr = dialogViewer('modellvergleiche-irt-with-brms', width = 1600, height = 1200)
runGadget(shinyAppDir(appDir = '../modellvergleiche-irt-with-brms'), viewer = vwr)
} # Run app in presized window
```

But I find it pritty ugly (especially the appDir = '../modellvergleiche-irt-with-brms' part).
Is there a better way to implement this? Maybe even a build in setting in RStudio I did not find yet?

Sincerely Famondir

Comment: I don't see what is ugly here. And why do you say "a new file"?

Comment: I had to create a new file additional to my app.R because otherwise I can't start the program via Run App Button in RStudio anymore. Additionally I step out of the folder to re enter it with appDir = '../modellvergleiche-irt-with-brms' so I can have the runapp.R in the same folder as app.R

Last: I can't use the reload button in the dialogViewer window.